# AppleScript get rid of missing value

Tags: applescript, missing-data

I'm extracting some number from a row within safari.

here is a small sample of the script

```
set DATA39 to "0"
set DATA40 to "0"

to getInputByClass2(theClass, num) -- defines a function with two inputs, theClass and num
    tell application "Safari" --tells AS that we are going to use Safari
        set input to do JavaScript "
document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1 -- uses JavaScript to set the variable input to the information we want
    end tell
    return input --tells the function to return the value of the variable input
end getInputByClass2



getInputByClass2("sortable DATAId", 1)
set theText to Unicode text
set DATA1 to getInputByClass2("sortable DATAId", 1)
###################################################################
getInputByClass2("sortable DATAId", 2)
set theText to Unicode text
set DATA to getInputByClass2("sortable DATA", 2)
###################################################################
```

I don't know how much data I'm collecting, so for now, I'm limiting the script to the first 30 results

(data1, data2 data3)

the only issue is when there is less than 30, I have the first result, then "missing value, missing value,missing value,"

I can't get rid of the missing value text?

I tried to set the variable before the script like

set DATA1 to missing value 
or 
set DATA1 to " "
or even 
set DATA1 to "0"

but no luck, I know my script is probably make sense, I'm sure there is a better way to script this, like maybe using "repeat ?"

UPDATE:
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "var outPut=[]; var arr=document.getElementsByClassName('sortable DATAId');for (var i in arr) {outPut.push(arr[i].innerHTML)};outPut;" in document 1
        --> {"

```
            <a href=\"/WebObjects/MYSupport.woa/wo/999AAHW44DhfffC5gg7Vh0/9.0.9.7.1.95.1.9.1.9.1.9.5.9.1.3.1\">DSID</a>

    ", "

            998877557

    ", "

            997777557

    ", "

            998877557

    ", "

            998877657

    ", missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value}
```

end tell
tell application "Script Editor"
    display dialog {"

```
            <a href=\"/WebObjects/MYSupport.woa/wo/999AAHW44DhfffC5gg7Vh0/9.0.9.7.1.95.1.9.1.9.1.9.5.9.1.3.1\">DSID</a>

    ", "

            998877557

    ", "

            997777557

    ", "

            998877557

    ", "

            998877657

    ", missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value} buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    --> error number -1700 from {"


            <a href=\"/WebObjects/MYSupport.woa/wo/999AAHW44DhfffC5gg7Vh0/9.0.9.7.1.95.1.9.1.9.1.9.5.9.1.3.1\">DSID</a>

    ", "

            998877557

    ", "

            997777557

    ", "

            998877557

    ", "

            998877657

    ", missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value} to string
```

Result:
error "Can’t make {\"

```
            <a href=\\\"/WebObjects/MYSupport.woa/wo/999AAHW44DhfffC5gg7Vh0/9.0.9.7.1.95.1.9.1.9.1.9.5.9.1.3.1\\\">DSID</a>

    \", \"

            998877557

    \", \"

            997777557

    \", \"

            998877557

    \", \"

            998877657

    \", missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value} into type string." number -1700 from {"


            <a href=\"/WebObjects/MYSupport.woa/wo/999AAHW44DhfffC5gg7Vh0/9.0.9.7.1.95.1.9.1.9.1.9.5.9.1.3.1\">DSID</a>

    ", "

            998877557

    ", "

            997777557

    ", "

            998877557

    ", "

            998877657

    ", missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value} to string
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put all elements into an array, use a javascript's loop to get the `innerHtml` of each element.

The output will be a list, use this list to get an item instead of having more than 30 variables.

```
set allData to my getInputByClass2("sortable DATAId")
-- to get the tenth value, use this --> item 10 of allData 

to getInputByClass2(theClass) -- this return a list of values
    tell application "Safari"
        set r to do JavaScript "var outPut=[]; var arr=document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "');for (var i in arr) {outPut.push(arr[i].innerHTML)};outPut;" in document 1
    end tell
    return strings of r --- this remove all 'Missing Value' from a list of strings
end getInputByClass2
```

---

If you want to limit the length of the list, use this

```
set allData to my getInputByClass2(theClass, 30) -- 30 values maximum
-- to get the tenth value in the list, use this --> item 10 of allData 

to getInputByClass2(theClass, num) --this return a list of values
    tell application "Safari"
        set r to do JavaScript "var n=" & num & "; var outPut=[]; var arr=document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "');var tLen=arr.length; if (n>tLen) {n=tLen;}; for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {outPut.push(arr[i].innerHTML)}; outPut;" in document 1
    end tell
    return strings of r --- this remove all 'Missing Value' from a list of strings
end getInputByClass2
```

---

**Update**, the `missing value` are from the elements without `innerHTML`.

To get rid of `missing value` from a list of **strings**, use this syntax (`set myList to strings of someList`).

I updated the scripts.

Comment: Thank you, the script look more clean alright, however the result is a bit unexpected (added on the question below)

Comment: that's great thank you very much, I'm very stupid but how do you save the result in the clipboard then? cause I have :script error "Can’t make {"
         
         
            <a href=\"/WebObjects/MYSupport.woa/wo/999AAHW44DhfffC5gg7Vh0/9.0.9.7.1.95.1.9.1.9.1.9.5.9.1.3.1\">DATA</a>

    ", "

            998877557

    ", "

            997777557

    ", "

            998877557

    ", "

            998877657
            
        "} into type string.

Comment: Here is an example for use of the clipboard in a script: `set the clipboard to myList` --<-- this put a list into the clipboard, now, the clipboard contains an AppleScript's object .`::` To get the clipboard in another script : `set anotherList to  the clipboard as list` -- this put the AppleScript's object as list into a variable. `::` But you can't paste the contents of the clipboard into any application because no application understand what is an AppleScript's object.

Comment: My text is too long to put in one comment ` :: ` This is impossible to answer correctly without informations, because I do not know what is the command you use to get this error, and I don't know what you want to do with the clipboard. `::` Please, start a new question.

Comment: That single line — `set myList to strings of someList` would have saved me hours if I had found it earlier. Thanks!!!